# Solving polynomial expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I want to minimize the following expression for fixed $r$ and $x \leq \sqrt{2}r$:

$$ d(y)=  \sqrt{r^2 + y^2} +  \sqrt{x^2 + (r-y)^2 -\sqrt{2} x (r-y) } $$

I have computed the following derivative:

$$ d'(y) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2 + y^2}} + \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot (2(r-y) \cdot (-1)+ \sqrt{2}x )}{\sqrt{x^2 + (r-y)^2 -\sqrt{2} x (r-y) }} $$

and tried to solve $d'(y)=0$. Here are my calculations (I have made a mistake, since the solutions do not match with the ones Wolfram Alpha gives. But I am not able to find it)

I hope any of you guys might give me some insight
\begin{align*}
     &&  \frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2 + y^2}} & = - \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot (2(r-y) \cdot (-1)+ \sqrt{2}x )}{\sqrt{x^2 + (r-y)^2 -\sqrt{2} x (r-y) }} \\
    \Leftrightarrow &&  -y \cdot  \sqrt{x^2 + (r-y)^2 -\sqrt{2} x (r-y) }  & = \left( y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \cdot  \sqrt{r^2 + y^2} \\
    \Rightarrow &&  y^2 \cdot \left(  x^2 + (r-y)^2 -\sqrt{2} x (r-y)\right)  & = \left( y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2  \cdot  r^2 + y^2 \\
    \Rightarrow &&  y^2 x^2 + y^2 (r-y)^2 + y^2 \sqrt{2} x (y-r) &= r^2 \left( y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 + y^2 \left( y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 \\ 
    \Leftrightarrow &&   y^2 x^2 + y^2 (r-y)^2 + y^2 \sqrt{2} x (y-r) &= r^2 \left( y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 \\ 
    &&&  + y^2 \cdot (y-r)^2 + y^2 \cdot \sqrt{2}(y-r) x + \frac{y^2x^2 }{2}\\  
%    
    \Leftrightarrow && \frac{y^2x^2 }{2}= r^2 \left( y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2   &= r^2 y^2 - y \cdot \left( 2 r^2 (r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}) \right) + r^2 \cdot(r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2 \\
%    
    \Leftrightarrow && 0 = y^2 \cdot \left( r^2 - \frac{x^2}{2} \right)& + y \cdot \left( - 2 r^2 (r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}) \right) + r^2 \cdot(r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2  \\
%    
    \Leftrightarrow && 0 = y^2  & + y \cdot \frac{- 2 r^2 (r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})}{ r^2 - \frac{x^2}{2}}  + \frac{r^2 \cdot(r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{ r^2 - \frac{x^2}{2}}   \\
    \end{align*}

Hence by $p,q$-Formula

$$ p:= - \frac{ 2 r^2 (r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})}{ r^2 - \frac{x^2}{2}} = -\frac{2 r^2}{r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} \quad q:= \frac{r^2 \cdot(r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{ r^2 - \frac{x^2}{2}} = \frac{r^2 (r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})}{r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}. $$

and thus

$$ y_{1,2}= - \frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{p}{2})^2 - q}= \frac{ r^2}{r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{ r^4}{(r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2} -  \frac{r^2 (r + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})}{r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}} =\frac{ r^2}{r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} \pm \frac{r \cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}{r- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}.   $$

But this solutions are clearly wrong, since wolfram gives 
$y_1 = r$ and $y_2 =  (\sqrt(2) r^2-r x)/(\sqrt(2) r+x)$. Which is pretty close to my solution however not entirely accurate.

**My question is, where did I make the mistake in the calculations?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So it is a function of both $x,y$, right? Or is $x$ a constant too?

Comment: you have forgot a $2$ in the first term of the derivative

Comment: You first choose $x \in [0,\sqrt{2}r]$ arbitrary and then look at the function $d(y)$. It is a parameter Problem.

Comment: The $2$ cancels with the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor coming from differentiating the square root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you made started on the sixth line, and involved an incorrect sign ($+$ instead of a $-$). I have reproduced the line below with the two corrections highlighted in red

$$\frac{y^2x^2 }{2}=r^2\left(y-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=r^2y^2-y\cdot\left(-2r^2\left(r\color{red}{-}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+r^2\left(r\color{red}{-}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$$

Thus the quadratic equation should be
$$0=y^2+y\cdot\frac{-2r^2\left(r-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{r^2-\frac{x^2}{2}}+\frac{r^2\cdot\left(r-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}{r^2-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Solving the quadratic will result in solutions that agree with the results from Wolfram Alpha, and be
$$y_{1,2}=\frac{r^2}{r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\pm\frac{\frac{rx}{\sqrt{2}}}{r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}$$